# Is it possible to concatenate columns from multiple files in Python, after truncating the column upto a certain row?

Tags: python, csv, file, data-science

I have 60 csv files and all of them look something like this.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDuNa.png)

Is it possible to concatenate 600 'ABPMean' values of all the files, in this case, for each file I need the 600 rows of the 'ABPMean' column, before the row where T0='Time and date'. I am supposed to use python to do this and I've looked everywhere but honestly don't understand where to start and if it even is possible, thank you.

Comment: Are you simply asking if it is possible to concatenate all 60 files into one big file? If so use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) to read in all the CSV files and concatenate them together, then save the output as one big CSV file.

Comment: No @snailor, I need to concatenate values of only the second row of all the 60 files, but before that I need to truncate the second column upto 600 values before the row where the value of first column = 'T0' (which is a single value in the third column). So sorry if this sounds complicated.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show a sample desired output ?